# chalk tagged template literals within strings

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, chalk

i am using chalk and i am constructing a string programatically (see `str` in the snippet below).

i would like chalk to honor my string as it would honor [tagged termplate literals](https://github.com/chalk/chalk#tagged-template-literal).

how can it be done?

```
const chalk = require('chalk');
const p = chalk`{bold BOLD}`

const str = `{bold BOLD}`
const q = chalk`${str}`

console.log(p == q ? "ok" : "!ok")
```

as you can see `p` and `q` are different - the code always outputs `!ok`.

Comment: `chalk(\`${str}\`)`

Comment: @JonasWilms Rather `chalk([str])`

Comment: @JonasWilms: that does not work for me

Comment: @Bergi: did you try what you offer? since it does not work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a [proxy for chalk](https://gist.github.com/bennadel/71eb3670ccf51daabf1658fb13b337b1#file-test2-js) that does just this

```
const chalk = require("chalk");

const chalkish = (parts, ...substitutions) => {
  const rawResults = [];
  const cookedResults = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    rawResults.push(parts.raw[i]);
    cookedResults.push(parts[i]);
    if (i < substitutions.length) {
      rawResults.push(substitutions[i]);
      cookedResults.push(substitutions[i]);
    }
  }

  const chalkParts = [cookedResults.join("")];
  chalkParts.raw = [rawResults.join("")];

  return (chalk(chalkParts));
}
```